# Radio Button testing in robotframework-selenium2 python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
*** Variables ***

${URL}          http://myurl


*** Test Cases ***      username          password
#Here I'm getting problem How should i write test cases for radio button    

*** Keywords ***

Go To First Chapter
    Go To  ${URL}

Find Radio Buttons
    Select Radio Button  ID  True
```

I dont know correct keyword or way to do this (as i'm beginner for this robotframework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Answer False To All Questions On First Chapter
    [Setup]  Go To First Chapter
    Select Radio Button    SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1    False
    Select Radio Button    SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1    False
    Select Radio Button    SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1    False
    Element Should Be Visible    SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1_expl
    Element Should Be Visible    SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_2_expl
    Element Should Be Visible    SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_3_expl
```

Will select false on all three questions and check that the element which indicates wrong answer is visible. Almost always your tests should have structure like

1. Setup
2. Do stuff
3. Check stuff
4. Teardown

http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html has documentation about the different keywords of Selenium2Library and https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/HowToWriteGoodTestCases will teach you something about how to write good test cases in RF.

Comment: Those images are inside of SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_X_expl elements, so checking if that parent is visible or not will do the same thing. To verify that element is not visible use Element Should Not Be Visible.

Comment: Then what is the problem you are facing? Click True, check that wanted element is visible. Click False, check that wanted element is visible. All keywords you need are Select Radio Button and Element Should Be Visible.

Comment: Do the green and red pictures differ in some way that RF can check? Maybe you could get the src via 'Get Element Attribute' and check if it is pointing to the red icon or green icon. Basically it will look like this:
${src}=    Get Element Attribute    ${your_img}@src
Should Not Contain    ${src}    green
Should Contain    ${src}    red

Comment: Page Should Contain Image   css=#SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1_corr img[src="/images/pics/pic_xMark.png"] and Page Should Contain Image   css=#SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1_corr img[src="/images/pics/pic_checkMark.png"]

Comment: Make another questions, since it is totally different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question right. How exactly do you want to test the radio buttons? Do you want to just assert they do exists and click on them?

Maybe you could consider using Helium - Python Selenium WebDriver wrapper which makes things easier:

```
from helium.api import *
start_chrome("http://pythoneval.zyante.com/ch01-introduction")
# scroll down to view the radio buttons
scroll_down(10)
# assert radio button True exists for question "1"
assert RadioButton("True", to_right_of=Text("1")).exists()
# assert radio button False exists for question "1"
assert RadioButton("False", to_right_of=Text("1")).exists()
# select the "True" answer for question number "1"
click(RadioButton("True", to_right_of=Text("1")))
# this displays the alert sometimes, if alert exists dismiss it by pressing ENTER
if Alert().exists():
    press(ENTER)
```

Similarly you can refer to radio buttons for other questions - there is no need to use the IDs such as SProgIntro_QSProgIntro_1. You can also use Python's unittest library to write complete test cases classes and make more sophisticated assertions.

More info at [heliumhq.com](http://heliumhq.com)

Disclosure: I'm one of the Helium developers.